# Downsampling and Gaussian Filtering in the Context of Scale Space Pyramids

Tags: image-processing, gaussian, downsampling, nyquist, scale-space

In the context of [scale space image pyramids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_space) using Gaussian filters I noticed that it's common to downsample the image after blurring with $\sigma = 2*\sigma_{init}$ . My question is: What is the relation between variance and downsampling? What is the proof that I'm not losing information when the image is downsampled after blurring with this factor?

I think this can easily be shown using Nyquist and the cut-off frequency of the Gaussian filter, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct, it has to do with the Cut Off frequency of the Gaussian Blur Filter in its Frequency Domain.

In order to see it, just apply a DFT (Using MATLAB it can be achieved by `fft` / `fft2`) and look on the absolute value.
Look for the -3dB point and you'll see.

There is also an intuitive explanation on the original article which say that blurring using Gaussian Kernel with $ \sigma $ means removing any detail which its size is smaller than $ \sqrt{ \sigma } $.